# Passing feature vector to Logistic Regression function of sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using LogisticRegression to model the Titanic problem of kaggle.com.
I want to use multiple variables like Age,Sex etc to model my sigmoid function.
The same method works fine if used with only 1 variable like Sex but it throws the following error when used for with multiple variables

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

My guess is that I am not using the reshape method correctly. 
PS : I am a beginner in python and sklearn library. Please go easy on me.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\abhi\Downloads\train.csv')

df.Age = df.Age.fillna(df.Age.mean)
df.Embarked = df.Embarked.fillna(df.Embarked.median)
x1 = df.Pclass
x2 = df.Sex
for i in range(len(x2)):
    if x2[i]=='male':
        x2[i]=1
    else: 
        x2[i]=0
#female,male 0,1

x3 = df.Age
x4 = df.SibSp
x5 = df.Parch
x6 = df.Ticket
x7 = df.Fare
x9 = df.Embarked
for i in range(len(x9)):
  if x9[i]=='C':
      x9[i]=0
  elif x9[i]=='Q': 
      x9[i]=1
  else :x9[i]=2

# C,Q,S = 0,1,2
# Creating a feature vector of multiple vectors

i2 = pd.DataFrame()
i2['Pclass'] = x1
i2['Sex'] = x2
i2['Age'] = x3
i2['SibSp'] = x4
i2['Parch'] = x5
i2['Fare'] = x7
i2['Embarked'] = x9
i2 = np.array(i2)
i2 = i2.reshape(-1,1)

ytrain = df.Survived
ytrain = np.array(ytrain)
ytrain = ytrain.reshape(-1,1)
c1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',solver='liblinear')
c1.fit(i2,ytrain,sample_weight=None)
c1.score(i2,ytrain,sample_weight=None)
```

Comment: You could have a look at http://hamelg.blogspot.in/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-28.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your code with deleting this line?
`i2 = i2.reshape(-1,1)`

Reshape `i2` to `(-1,1)` will transform `i2`to one dimensional array with length of total number of elements in the `i2`. This is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: On removing that line I am receiving this error:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'